# A nonempty class of isomorphic groups defines a group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic, foundations

The context of this question is from the definition of the sporadic Mathieu group $M_{23}$, which (in one possible definition) is the stabilizer of a point in $M_{24}$, which is a certain subgroup of $S_{24}$ (a permutation group on $24$ points). When I read this I was a bit surprised since they haven't specified *which* point is to be stabilized, but I assume that the content here is that it doesn't matter, since different stabilizers yield isomorphic subgroups.

Which brings me to the question: is it possible to define a single group given a set of isomorphic groups? Of course in this case we could define $M_{23}$ as the stabilizer of the first point, assuming that the $24$ original points are distinguishable to begin with, for example if they were the numbers $1,\dots,24$ and I could pick out $1$ specifically. But in more general contexts this can be problematic, especially for sets which have no distinguished members, such as the set of all free ultrafilters of $\Bbb N$.

If I have a family $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ of groups for some nonempty index set $I$ such that $G_i\cong G_j$ for all $i,j\in I$, is it possible to define a group $G$ such that $G\cong G_i$ for all $i$? By the observation above, if there is some term $x$ for which $x\in I$ is provable, then it would suffice to take $G=G_x$, but what if there is no such $x$?

Comment: I'm a bit troubled by your saying "some term $x$ for which $x \in I$ is provable". If you're assuming $I$ is nonempty then $x \in I$ *is* provable, and you've answered your own question! And if there is no such $x$ then $I$ is empty, so there are no groups to consider and the problem is vacuous.

Comment: @CliveNewstead It's difficult to distinguish the notions in usual English, but there is a difference between $\vdash x\in I$ and $\vdash\exists x:x\in I$. Obviously the first implies the second, but the second does not imply the first, for example as I mentioned when $I$ is the set of free ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$ (there are free ultrafilters in $\sf ZFC$, but there are no *definable* free ultrafilters).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I hope I made it clear that the question has more to do with definability in a theory than groups themselves, and so I'm inclined to consider it more (set-theory) or some other foundational topic for its connections to models and provability than (elementary-set-theory), which seems to cover more explicit set-related topics like set operations and relations.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro No, it is not set theory.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Perhaps (logic) then.

Comment: (But feel free to re-add the tag, if you think it may help. But this may lead to answers such as the following, which I doubt is what you are after: Consider the natural well-ordering of $V_\omega$ in type $\omega$, and define $M_{23}$ as the first group (in its isomorphism class) according to the well-ordering.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Not a bad first approach to the problem, though. It generalizes to the question as stated if you assume a well order of the universe (i.e. global choice) so that you can pick out the least group under the well-order that is isomorphic to the $G_i$, and if the $G_i$ are finite then your solution should actually work as-is.

Comment: Mario, why the heavy use of global choice? Look at the set of those groups with minimal rank.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You would still need a definable well-order of that particular set, and so to make the claim in general you would need a sequence of ever-larger definable well-orders, which I'm pretty sure also amounts to global choice.

Comment: Erm, you asked only about a particular family of groups indexed by $I$. Not anything else. Your comment hints that you want to consider ***all*** kinds of these groups and isomorphism classes. But worry not, you still don't have to do anything there. I'm writing an answer that you may or may not be fond of.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay, I see what you mean, I guess I was assuming that the solution would take the form $G=F(G_{i,i\in I})$ for some term $F$ that does not depend on $G_i$ but I suppose that need not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Define in specific detail? Of course not. You can choose one from the collection.

But why choose? Why do anything at all? We can revisit the definition of cardinal in $\sf ZF$, as well cardinal arithmetic that goes along with it. Specifically, you might not be able to have a choice of representatives there.

Instead we abstract the notion of cardinal, we assign a certain set, using Scott's trick, to the equivalence class (proper class) of sets under equipollence. We then proceed to calculate addition and multiplication and so on, based on picking an arbitrary representatives from two classes, and showing that we can find a set with the wanted properties defined from those.

Here we can do the same thing. If $\{(G_i,\cdot_i)\mid i\in I\}$ is a set of groups which are pairwise isomorphic then we can say that they define a group $G$ which is abstract. In order to do some calculation in $G$ you pick an arbitrary $G_i$ to do the calculation in, and use the fact that there is an isomorphism between every two, so the result doesn't matter.

In some sense, this group is "pointless", and we only interested in knowing that it is isomorphic to those $G_i$'s, not what its points are. If you have two "pointless groups", $G$ and $H$ their product can be defined as the set $\{G_i\times H_j\mid i\in I,j\in J\}$ (where $\{ H_j\mid j\in J\}$ correspond to $H$, of course).

And just like in cardinal arithmetic over $\sf ZF$, if you already know that *every* group can be represented as a "pointless group", then you can just pick two representatives and consider the pointless group representing the product of these two groups. Of course, using Scott's trick you can define canonical pointless groups like that.

Comment: I'd be happy to hear a verbal criticism as well!

Comment: I see now what you mean by "an answer I may or may not be fond of". I wonder whether it is possible to prove that my construction is impossible, possibly by using the fact that it would have to be permutation-invariant under permutations of $I$ to extract explicit isomorphisms between the $G_i$.

Comment: Mario, there are categories which are not concrete, and we cannot have this sort of choice of representative even if we wanted. This is not a big deal, here you just abstract the choice of representative to the meta-language and claim that it doesn't really matter for any useful purpose. It works for cardinal arithmetic without choice quite well.

Comment: I know, but it tends to make for a lot of meta-mathematical hoops to jump through and makes formalization a pain in general, so I like to avoid it when possible, and I was hoping that $\sf Grp$ might admit such a counstruction. Your answer was well written, though (even if it has to take the disappointing negative stance). +1

Comment: Well, for this you just really need global choice, to choose one from each class. It's probably equivalent to global choice, too.